# Notification for answer can't be viewed

Tags: support, notifications

I posted a question last night: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808241/master-theorem-and-logarithms/808280?noredirect=1#808280

And when I look at my notifications I see that there has been an answer:

[image]

*However*, when I visit the question I can't see anything. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3):

The answer has been deleted.  Once you have earned [10K reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (or been elected ♦-moderator), you'll be able to see it. (The other possibility is that the answer is undeleted at some point.)